# Computing adjoint operator in $(\ell_2,\|.\|_2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I tried deriving the adjoint operator for
$T(x_1,x_2,...)=(\frac{1}{2}(x_1+x_2 ) , \frac{1}{4}(x_2+x_3 ), ..., \frac{1}{2^n}(x_{n}+x_{n+1} ), ...)$ in $(\ell_2,\|.\|_2)$ but ended up with a very complex equation.
Can somebody help me out?

Is there a way I can use the orthonormal basis for $\ell_2$ to simplify my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left<T^{\ast}e_{n},e_{m}\right>&=\left<e_{n},Te_{m}\right>\\
&=\left<e_{n},(0,...,1/2^{m},...)\right>\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2^{m}}\delta_{nm}.
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\|T(x_{n})\|_{2}&=\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{x_{n}+x_{n+1}}{2^{n}}\right)^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{x_{n}}{2^{n}}+\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{2^{n}}\right)^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{x_{n}}{2^{n}}\right)^{2}\right)^{1/2}+\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{2^{n}}\right)^{2}\right)^{1/2}\\
&\leq\dfrac{1}{2}\|(x_{n})\|_{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}\|(x_{n})\|_{2}\\
&=\|(x_{n})\|_{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Hmm. It's supposed to be self-adjoint though, I think!

Comment: Yes, you just need to compare $\left<Te_{n},e_{m}\right>$, the same result is obtained.

Comment: I see. You're taking a specific $x$ in the space. However, I think we first need to prove that $T$ is bounded before concluding that $T^*$ exists.

Comment: Actually densely defined operators admit adjoint anyway.

Comment: $T$ is a bounded operator with norm at most $\frac 4 3$.

Comment: Does the adjoint operator have a closed form? I've never seen an adjoint operator represented like that.

Comment: It is self-adjoint, so it is $T$.

Comment: The equation that you derived hols only for one specific pair in the Hilbert space. How do we know it always holds?

Comment: The set $\text{span}(e_{n})$ is dense in $l^{2}$, it suffices to check on each $e_{n}$.